# Executing commands with ssh and shell script using variables on a remote machine

Tags: shell-script, ssh, remote, variable-substitution

I'd like to execute a command and script located on a remote machine with a script on a local machine. I know it's possible to execute these kind of commands with `ssh`, so I made:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh username@target 'cd locationOf/theScript/; ./myScript.sh'
```

It works perfectly.
I'd like this script to be more generic, using variables. Now, it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOCATION=locationOf/theScript/
EXEC=myScript.sh
ssh username@target 'cd ${LOCATION}; ./${EXEC}'
```

And I get this error: `bash: ./: is a directory`

I guess the remote machine doesn't know these variables. So is there a way to *export* them to the target ?

Comment: See also [Using exec in find over ssh from shell script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139766/using-exec-in-find-over-ssh-from-shell-script/139800#139800), [How can I run a script immediately after connecting via SSH?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9883/how-can-i-run-a-script-immediately-after-connecting-via-ssh), [How can I set environment variables for a remote rsync process?](http://superuser.com/questions/207200/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-remote-rsync-process)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know an easy way of exporting environmental variables to target, but your script might work if you replace `'` with `"`. With `'`s the string `'cd ${LOCATION}; ./${EXEC}'` gets passed verbatim, but with

```
ssh username@target "cd ${LOCATION}; ./${EXEC}"
```

variable substitution is done locally.

Note that the values of `LOCATION` and `EXEC` are passed to the remote shell, so this only works if they don't contain any shell special characters.